# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'heatmap' in Spyder

Tags: python, seaborn, spyder, heatmap

I downloaded the `seaborn` module and I am unable to use the `heatmap` function in Spyder (latest version), please help!

I also tried installing:

1. `statsmodels`
2. `fastcluster`

And also tried downgrading `matplotlib` but didn't work

```py
import seaborn 
seaborn.heatmap(Data_Set7)
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-13-0336b4e3860e>", line 1, in <module>
    seaborn.heatmap(Data_Set7)

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'heatmap'
```

Comment: What version of the seaborn module are you using?  Do you have a local file named `seaborn.py`?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you create file `seaborn.py`? If you have own `seaborn.py` then `import seaborn` loads your file and it can't find `heatmap` in your file.

Comment: Can you please comment how you installed `seaborn`? Which version of `seaborn` do you have? Did you try using the terminal just to test if the code works there?

Comment: @JohnGordon Latest verion which is '0.11.1' . Yes, I do have a local file seaborn-0.11.0-py_0

Comment: @furas OK, I'll keep that in mind. No, I didn't created the file seaborn.py

Comment: @bruno-uy Using pip install seaborn. Yes I did check but it gave a message like 'seaborn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: message `'seaborn' is not recognized as an internal or external command` you could get only if you would run only `seaborn` (without `pip install`) in console/terminal. You can't get it if you run `pip install seaborn`

Comment: in code after `import seaborn` check `print( seaborn.__file__ )` to see what file it loaded.

Comment: @furas it prints C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py

Comment: path seems OK but you can open it in text editor to see what you have inside. You could also check `print( seaborn.__version__ )`

Comment: I deleted the seaborn package from Anaconda Navigator-->Environments and ran the Spyder IDE from Anaconda Navigator itself. It solved the problem. Anyways thank you for all of your help.